# how show the data from array list in php

Tags: php

i want to store retrieved data from database into an array list with limit.And display the data from that array list one by one with next button.have any answer for this?

Comment: What kind of knowledge do you have with PHP/MySQL?

Comment: I assume you're talking about a paginated result set?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to have a look at this kind of websites : http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Comment: have you confused with this question?

Comment: Your question seems to mean you have a lack of knowledge in php/mysql development. It's why you should start by doing some tutorials.

Comment: <?php
include ("db.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ques_id FROM questionbank order by ques_id limit 5 ");

while($obj=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$ad1[$obj['ques_id']]++;//Used an array and inserted the database query results into it.
}
$rand_keys=array_rand($ad1,1); //Did a random array function
echo "First random id = ".$ad1[$rand_keys[0]];
echo "<br>Second random id = ".$ad1[$rand_keys[1]];

?>
 <!--Its not working. Have any solution for this. -->
i make a code for this question but its not working...can u help me